# Can't use sipml5 client on firefox (windows & OSX)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm trying to make a call by using sipml5 client (http://sipml5.org/ ) or click2dial (http://click2dial.org/) on firefox 20 (Windows & OSX) but it doesn't work. When I try to make call using Chrome, it works fine on both windows & OSX. Please help me how to configure firefox to work with sipml5 or click2dial. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC is not allowed in firefox yet. https://code.google.com/p/sipml5/wiki/Enable_WebRTC
You must use webrtc4all (Windows only) to allow this in Opera, IE and Firefox.  https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/